# Method of abstract clas found cannot be found in build jar

Tags: java, maven, inheritance, abstract-class, nosuchelementexception

I have a maven project where a class inherits from an abstract class.

When i run the project in eclipse, everything is fine, no problems when i call inherited methods of the implementation.

After building the jar with the maven goal 'clean package' and running it from terminal, a NoSuchMethodException appears when calling a inherited method.

Comment: by fixing it. but without seeing any code/more context, there's not much more for us to say about it

Comment: Where is the abstract class from? Your own source code that gets compiled by `package`? Or from some library jar file that you deployed the wrong version of (which is almost always the cause of NoSuchMethodError)?

Comment: how about ```mvn clean install```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the abstract class comes from a dependency of your project. Building a jar with `clean package` does not include dependencies into your artifact.

Comment: And if the dependency was missing altogether, you'd get a `ClassNotFoundError`. So my guess is that the dependency jar is present on the deployment but it is of the wrong version.